# Using div element in data-content of Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display pop of message using Bootstrap Popover.
Here is my html code:

```
<div class="numberCircle">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Book Information"
        data-content="Booked By : hari <br> Booked from : Bookings.com">222</a>
</div>
```

I want to show the message like in html tags but it shows like below:

[image: popup message display]

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
```

I want to show my `data-content` element something like this:

[image: real content]

Comment: try https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3722#issuecomment-18156077

Comment: data-html="true" in "<a>" tag was missed in my case